# XML Parsing Error while passing multiple parameters

Tags: xml

I am continuously getiing this error when I try to pass two parameters in with my URl:
It works fine when I pass only one parameter:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://helloApplet.xml
Line Number 6, Column 65:

```
<Content type="url" href="helloApplet.jsp?name=xyz&password=12345"/>
 ----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` indicates the start of a [character/entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref) in XML.

If you want a `&` as data then you need to use a reference for it: `&amp;`

(Or you can use a CDATA block, but not inside an attribute value).